# Finding the highest value within a single field

Tags: vb.net, csv

I want to find the highest numerical value in a CSV field as this will determine the next highest number.

```
Dim founditem() As String = Nothing
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\testtests.csv")
    Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)
    Do While item(8) = choice
        If weeknumber < item(9) Then
            weeknumber += 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Next
```

I am getting an "index is out of bounds" exception. Why?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Very funny(!) You know exactly what I mean.

Comment: No, sorry. Your code is showing a solution, so where is the problem? Does it throw an exception? Does it not yield the expected result? Or What?

Comment: Ohh yeah sorry, it produces an error which says that the index is out of bounds.

Comment: you need to remove empty elements when splitting (the last emty element), so just use the right overload. oh, and 'I want' is not welcome here.

Answer (score 4):

- .NET arrays are zero-bound. Their indexes range from `0` to `number
  of columns - 1`.
- Do you have ten columns? Because of `item(9)` you would at least need
  to have ten columns.
- Note that also empty fields at the end of the line must be separated
  by commas in a CSV file. If you have 10 columns, a line must always have 9 commas.
- Also an empty line at the end of the file might cause the problem
  because it will yield exactly one empty item for that line, instead
  of ten.

Add a test for the line length:

```
Do While item.Length = 10 AndAlso item(8) = choice
    If weeknumber < item(9) Then
        weeknumber += 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

If this does not help, set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method, step through it and inspect the variables. The Visual Studio debugger makes it very easy to find most such errors. Even the Exception tells you the line and column numbers of the faulty spot.

Comment: Yes, indeed I do have 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a CSV file is much more than splitting by comma. You may encounter nested commas, such as when comma is part of the value. Your way of parsing will retrieve weird results on such data. You can also have nested newlines, such as when a newline character is part of the value. So your CSV record can span multiple lines. There may be more issues out there, which I don't remember off top of my head.

Better be using a 3rd party CSV parser, such as this one:

- [KBCsv @ Codeplex](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/).